# Update fields to use a different FieldFormatter during an update hook

Tags: plugins

I have a drupal.org module that has changed its fieldformatter ID in a later version and I need the update hook to update all isntance of the content to use the new formatter, but cant seem to figure out how to do this.

e.g.

```
/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'field_example_simple_text' formatter.
 *
 * @FieldFormatter(
 *   id = "example_field_formatter",
 *   module = "example",
 *   label = @Translation("example"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "example_field_type"
 *   }
 * )
 */
```

has changed to

```
/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'field_example_simple_text' formatter.
 *
 * @FieldFormatter(
 *   id = "new_example_field_formatter",
 *   module = "example",
 *   label = @Translation("example"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "new_example_field_type"
 *   }
 * )
 */
```

I need to update the content/fields to be using the new formatter as it overwrites the previous one.

Comment: See my response here for an idea: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/278337/change-target-type-of-entity-reference-field-in-update-hook/278355#278355

Answer (score 0):

The plugin definitions you've posted are for new fields to build the options when configuring a field formatter in UI. For existing fields you have to update the field formatter in config.

For example:

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity\EntityViewDisplay;

function mymodule_update_8001() {
  foreach (EntityViewDisplay::loadMultiple() as $display) {
    foreach ($display->getComponents() as $name => $options) {
      if (isset($options['type']) && $options['type'] == 'old_formatter') {
        $options['type'] = 'new_formatter';
        $display->setComponent($name, $options)
          ->save();
      }
    }
  }
}
```